# Why does this Scala bubbleSorting not work?

Tags: scala, bubble-sort

This is bubble sorting code implement by scala, but it is doesn't work correctly.

```
implicit class ArrayWrappedSwap[A](array: Array[A]){
    def swap(current:Int,target:Int): Unit ={
      val tmp = array(target)
      array(target) = array(current)
      array(current) = tmp
    }
 }
 def bubbleSort[A](arr:Array[A])(implicit ordering: Ordering[A]):Array[A]={
    var continueSort = true

    arr.indices.foreach(time⇒ {

      if (!continueSort) {
        return arr

      } else {
        continueSort = false

        (0 until (arr.length - time)).foreach { index ⇒

          if (ordering.compare(arr(index), arr(arr.length - 1 - time)) > 0) {
            arr.swap(index, arr.length - 1 - time)
            continueSort = true
          }

        }
      }
    })
    arr
 }
println(bubbleSort(Array(1,3,1,2,3)).mkString(","))
```

it is output 1,3,1,2,3

Comment: Did you debug the code?

Comment: And why all the complexity with the implicits? Get the sort working first. As @YuvalItzchakov says, step through it in a debugger. But what you have there is not a bubblesort: from Wikipedia: "compares each pair of *adjacent* items "

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed version that really does a bubblesort. I have no idea how you expected the other version to work, so this just does the obvious "compares each pair of adjacent items"

```
  implicit class ArrayWrappedSwap[A](array: Array[A]) {
    def swap(current: Int, target: Int): Unit = {
      val tmp = array(target)
      array(target) = array(current)
      array(current) = tmp
    }
  }
  def bubbleSort[A](arr: Array[A])(implicit ordering: Ordering[A]): Array[A] = {
    var continueSort = true

    arr.indices.foreach(time => {

      if (!continueSort) {
        return arr

      } else {
        continueSort = false

        (time  until arr.length-1).foreach { index =>

          if (ordering.compare(arr(index), arr(index + 1)) > 0) {
            arr.swap(index, index+1)
            continueSort = true
          }

        }
      }
    })
    arr
  }                                               //> bubbleSort: [A](arr: Array[A])(implicit ordering: Ordering[A])Array[A]
  println(bubbleSort(Array(1, 3, 1, 2, 3)).mkString(","))
```

Comment: I think these kind of questions need to be downvoted and closed, or improved and then answered. OP doesn't deserve your effort.

Comment: Yeah, you have a point. There's lots wrong with that code still.